# How to delete an item from a state array without creating a new Array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am new in React and learning context. While learning I came across a project for creating a cart where value is added and deleted.
Adding an item part is achieved but I am not able to implement the remove functionality.

This is my Item component where I am handeling the item array and adding them

```
 import { CartContext } from "./Cart-Context";
import { useContext } from "react";
// import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import React from "react";

const Items = () => {
  const ItemArr = [
    { name: "item1" },
    { name: "item2" },
    { name: "item3" },
    { name: "item4" },
    { name: "item5" },
  ];
  const context = useContext(CartContext);

  const handleClick = (item) => {
    context.updateCart([...context.cart, item]);
   console.log(context.cart);
  };
  const handleRemove = (item) =>{
  const newList = context.cart.filter((newItem, key)=>{
    return newItem !== key
  })
  console.log(newList);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {ItemArr.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {item.name}
            <button
              onClick={()=>{handleClick(item)}}
            >
              Add To Cart
            </button>
            <button onClick={()=>{handleRemove(item)}}>Remove from Cart</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Items;
```

This is my provider component

```
    import { useState } from "react";
import { CartContext } from "./Cart-Context";



const CartProvider = (props) =>{
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    const [removeCart, setRemoveCart] = useState([])

    return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{cart: cart ,updateCart: setCart, remove: removeCart , updateRemove: setRemoveCart}}>
            {
                props.children
            }
    </CartContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default CartProvider;
```

Now on click of remove button I want to remove that specific item from the cart array (context.cart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `filter` method is not correct. I assume you want to remove the provided `item`, but the filter is not referring it. You're comparing the index of the current element with the element itself, which will always be `false` as long as the item is not a number, which is the same as the index. Also, the newly created list is not used to update the cart.
I think you will keep all items in the cart which are not the provided one, so
try this instead:

```js
const handleRemove = (item) =>{
  const newList = context.cart.filter((newItem)=>{
    return newItem !== item
  })
  context.updateCart(newList);
  console.log(newList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set new cart content:

```js
  const handleRemove = (item) =>{
  const newList = context.cart.filter((newItem, key)=>{
    return newItem !== key
  });

  context.updateCart(newList);

  console.log(newList);
  }
```